# Dictionary whose key is independent on the order of elements it contains

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

I would like to create a dictionary in Python, whose key would be independent on the order of elements it contains. Here is example:

```
items = {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 5}
comb = {(key1, key2): 0 for key2 in items.keys() for key1 in items.keys() if key1 != key2}
```

Outputs:

```
{(1, 2): 0, (1, 4): 0, (2, 1): 0, (4, 2): 0, (4, 1): 0, (2, 4): 0}
```

But I would only like to have:

```
{(1, 2): 0, (1, 4): 0, (2, 4): 0}
```

So the key (1, 2) should be equal to (2, 1). That would also need to be true for tuples of length more then 2 (e.g. (2, 3, 4) = (4, 3, 2)).

Comment: @Bakuriu: The OP is looping over the keys, not testing containment. It's still better to drop the `keys` call, but using `keys` won't result in the massive performance degradation that would happen when testing containment with `keys`.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, I missed the second `for`... However,as you noted, it's still useless. Also in python3 it may add only a small overhead, but in python2 it will create a list of keys before looping, almost doubling the time take by the dict-comprehension.

Comment: @Bakuriu: You're completely right that it's useless and wasteful—and, more important, it makes the code more verbose and harder to read… but you're optimizing the wrong part first. The wasted cost of trying to build `combinations` out of a cartesian product (especially given that in a comment on an answer he indicated wanting to do this for 3 or more) is going to swamp the cost of unnecessarily building some small lists…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> {keys: 0 for keys in itertools.combinations(items, 2)}
{(1, 2): 0, (2, 4): 0, (1, 4): 0}
```

with [`dict.fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.fromkeys) (Only use `dict.fromkeys` when the value is immutable; the value is shared by all entries):

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(itertools.combinations(items, 2), 0)
{(1, 2): 0, (2, 4): 0, (1, 4): 0}

>>> dict.fromkeys(itertools.combinations(items, 3), 0)
{(1, 2, 4): 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have order-independent keys in a general case, you can use [frozensets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set) as keys instead of tuples:

```
>>> {frozenset((key1, key2)): 0 for key2 in items.keys() for key1 in items.keys() if key1 != key2}
{frozenset({2, 4}): 0, frozenset({1, 2}): 0, frozenset({1, 4}): 0}
```

For the specific case of the OP, the previously mentioned solution will be better. However, if there is a need for really order-independent keys, the solution I proposed might be a way to go and more elegant (and faster) than sorting the indices.